# Loading Encrypted Records

Tags: encryption, platform-encryption, shield-encryption, dbamp

I have been looking to see what other people have experienced regarding loading records into an environment with encryption enabled.  If I were to use a tool such as DBamp, to load records into an an environment with encryption enabled, would this slow down the load time?  I am trying to see if I would be more ahead to just load the records, and encrypt after the fact. Or would the encryption occur fast enough, that we wouldn't really see any impact during the load?  Any information would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: see https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/209112/what-is-the-performance-penalty-for-deterministic-platform-encryption for some insight

Comment: @cropredy That's helpful! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encryption does have a non-zero impact on processing time, but it should be insignificant enough that you shouldn't worry about it. I don't know of any documentation that describes how much extra time would be added, but it should be a *very* small fraction of a second, probably immeasurable compared to the much larger variations based on ping times, database load/save times, etc. Enabling the encryption *after* loading will likely result in Salesforce taking far longer to encrypt the values asynchronously afterwards.

Comment: That was my assumption, but just wanted to see if anyone else had experience.  I owe you lunch.  Thanks for the information!