# Momentarily Disable Encryption

Tags: encryption, platform-encryption, shield-encryption

This is an odd problem, but nonetheless, I am stumped.  Has anyone ever had to disable encryption in order to get bulk data loads to succeed?  Right now, we are encrypting fields on the account object.  When a large load of account records is kicked off, we are seeing a significant percentage of records fail due to CPU issues.  I have been reading [This](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/209112/what-is-the-performance-penalty-for-deterministic-platform-encryption), and I saw that they experienced a somewhat notable performance impact when utilizing encryption.  Is there a way to momentarily disable encryption(short of pulling the key)?  I am just trying to narrow down the causes of the CPU issue.  Any information would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: How do you know that disabling Encryption would solve your issue, can you try same in FULL Copy Sandbox and then reconfirm? Yes it would increase CPU time, but wont increase exponetially, 10 sec is quite good CPU time for almost all operatons

Comment: We don't know if that is the case @PranayJaiswal, however I was just curious if there was an easy way to do so.  We have started by disabling validation rules/triggers to see if that helps with the performance issues.

Comment: why not make the bulk api batch size smaller?

Answer (score 1):

You should open a support case for this.  That is *not* expected behavior.

Comment: Thanks @john!  We are disabling the validation rules/Triggers first.  If that doesn't help with the performance, I will open a case.  Thank you!

Comment: That's a good idea - worth checking that and ruling it out.  Support can definitely help if that doesn't work.